# Query DNS RR with timestamp python

Tags: c#, python, networking, dns

Hi and thank you in advance.

I'm trying to query DNS records using python.
Currently I'm able to query using dnspython library and the records are pulling with no problem. However, I've been unable to retrieve any timestamps for these records. I'm implementing a MSSQL DB to store and handle this data and need a way to check changes made to records and timestamps would be the simplest way I believe to spot changes.

**My question is ->**  Is it possible to retrieve the record timestamps with python? If so, are there any packages that can help me out or resources I could read up on.

*Additional information:*
I'm using C# and wmi calls to a test DNS server running on a MS Server to insert fake records. I can alternatively try to do this with C# (not sure how yet) but I've been asked to complete the task in python if possible.

I'm interning and still in school so DNS is completely new to me as well as C#/.net stuff

**EDIT(per comment):**
Here is how i'm outputting the dns records currently. I get a TTL but it doesn't tell me anything about when the record was created/updated last. the TTL value is always the same value.

```
for qtype in 'A', 'AAAA', 'MX', 'NS', 'TXT', 'SOA':
                try:
                    answer = resolver.query(domainSelected, qtype, raise_on_no_answer=False)
                    for retAns in answer:
                        if qtype == "A":
                            aIP = retAns.to_text()
                        print(qtype, ': ', retAns.to_text())
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)  
                    print("\n")
``
```

Comment: What do you mean by timestamp? The DNS TTL value for each record? If so, it is available into each object that dnspython gives you back after a query, look at http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/dns.rdataset.Rdataset-class.html you have a `ttl` attribute. Also to optimize your question here you should show some code and what you have tried, and errors you get, if any.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek updated. thx for recommendation hopefully this clarifies things? my ttl is always a static # 3600 in my case. I'm new to DNS and as i understand there is a timestamp made for each record taken from the server clock for when it was inserted or last updated.

Comment: No,the TTL is the only thing you will get, no "timestamp".If you query an authoritative server it is expected that you get always the same fixed TTL value. You will get different values each time if you query a recursive nameserver. TTL means Time To Live, it is a metadata attached to records so that authoritative server gives a reply to a recursive nameserver saying at the same time "you can cache locally this value for so many seconds" (the TTL is in seconds).The SOA record is special it has a "serial" value. It is often either the unix epoch or YYYYMMDDXXX,and it changes if content changes.

Comment: Also relevant to your code, to be defensive, remember that you may get different record types than the one you expect, that is you can query for an A record but get back a CNAME one. This is legit. So your code has to look at the results of the query, dnspython provides everything you need to look inside the resource records retrieved.